# Hi guys, how do i show the users name on the navbar once they have logged into onto the website?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, mongoose

I have managed to get my users to sign up and they are able to login to the website. Their personal information is stored on mongoose and I am able to see it. If the user is not registered, they aren't able to log in, and only if they are registered then are they able to log in. How do I display their name in the navbar on the person icon when they are logged in and when they logged out only the icon shows?

Here is the code.

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styling/Header.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ShoppingBasketIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ShoppingBasket';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import logo from '../media/logo.png';


function Header({ click }) {
    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
    const { cartItems } = cart;
    
    const getCartCount = () => {
        return cartItems.reduce((qty, item) => Number(item.qty) + qty, 0);
    };
    return (
        <nav className='header'>
            <Link to="/">
                <div className="header_logo">
                    <img src={logo} /> 
                </div> 
            </Link>
            <ul className='header_links'>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/men'>
                        <span>Men</span>
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/women'>
                        <span>Women</span>
                    </Link>
                </li>   
            </ul>

            <div className='header_links2'>
                <div className="header_search">
                    <input type="text" className="header_searchInput"/> 
                    <SearchIcon className ="header_searchIcon"/>  
                </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/login' className='header_login'>
                                <PersonIcon />
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/basket' className>
                                <ShoppingBasketIcon />
                            <span className="header_basketCount" >{ getCartCount()}</span>
                            </Link>
                        </li>      
                </ul>
                
            </div>
            <div onClick={ click} className='header_ham_menu'>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import logo from '../media/logo.png';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

import "../styling/Login.css"
function Login() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    })
    const onChangeInput = e => { 
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setUser({...user, [name]: value})
    }
    const submitLogin = async e => { 
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.post('/user/login', { ...user })
            localStorage.setItem('login', true)
            window.location.href='/'  
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.response.data.msg)  
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="login">
            <Link to ='/'>
                <img className="login_logo"
                    src={logo}
                />
            </Link>
            <div className="login_container">
                <h1>Sign in</h1>
            
                <form onSubmit={ submitLogin}>
                    <h5>E-Mail</h5>
                    <input
                        name='email'
                        type="email"
                        value={user.email}
                        onChange={onChangeInput}
                        placeholder = 'E-mail'
                    />              
                    <h5>Password</h5>
                    <input
                        name='password'
                        type="password"
                        value={user.password}
                        onChange={onChangeInput}
                        placeholder = 'Password'
                    />
                    
                    <button type='submit' className="login_signinbtn">Log In</button>
                </form>
                <p>
                    By signing in you agree to the website condisions of use and sale. 
                    Please see our Privacy notice, our cookies notice and our interest Based
                    Ads Notice
                </p>
                <button className="login_regbtn">
                    <Link to='/register'>
                    Create an  Account
                    </Link>
                </button>
            </div>
        
        </div>
    )
}
export default Login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using redux based on the this line:

`const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);`

In that case you could save the signed in user in redux and then you can create a selector to show it anywhere on the site.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();

function onCreateUser(newUser) {
  // I'm assuming the request returns the user
  const response = await axios.post('/user/login', newUser);
  dispatch(setSignedInUser(user));
}
```

```js
// In some component
const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user)

return (
  <>
   {!!user && <div>Hello {user.name}</div>}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you are storing login true, you can store name in local storage too. In case you feel user info is sensitive, you can encode or encrypt before storing. Use localStorage.getItem("yourkey") to get data from storage